# Vuex Module Decorator: How to access store within a module

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuex-module-decorators

I have been experimenting with vuex module decorator to keep good typescript in my vuex stores. But im having difficulties trying to access the store without getting type definition issues.

I am using:

- nuxt with 'nuxt-typescript' and 'vue2-composition-api',
- vuex with 'vuex-module-decorator' setup with getModule for SSR,

Here is a basic example of what im attempting:

**store/index.ts**

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import User from './user'
import Basket from './basket'

export function useUserModule(store: Store<any>): UserModule {
    return getModule(UserModule, store)
}

export function useBasketModule(store: Store<any>): BasketModule {
    return getModule(BasketModule, store)
}
```

**store/user.ts**

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module({
    name: 'user',
    namespaced: true,
    stateFactory: true,
    preserveState: true,
})
export default class UserModule extends VuexModule {
    user: IUser | null = null

@Action
    async doSomthingWithUser(request: object) {
      console.log('success!, called from basket module')
    }
}
```

**store/basket.ts**

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import { useUserModule } from '.'

@Module({
    name: 'basket',
    namespaced: true,
    stateFactory: true,
    preserveState: true,
})
export default class BasketModule extends VuexModule {
    basket: IBasket | null = null

@Action
    async doUserAction(request: object) {
      
      const userStore = useUserModule(this.store)
      //Property 'store' does not exist on type 'BasketModule'

      userStore.doSomthingWithUser({stuff:true})
    }
}
```

```
Property 'store' does not exist on type 'BasketModule'
```

The problem is `this.store` DOES exist when I console log `this`!
The examples I found [here](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/issues/83) use the `this.$store` which doesnt exist for me.
eg: `getModule(MobuleB, this.$store)`

I have also tried using the traditional approach to nuxt SSR described in the docs [decorators with ServerSideRender](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators)...but exactly same situation.

Everything works fine...but IDE is giving error, im new to typescript and I think the module doesnt have the type definition for store. Anyone know how I can assign a definition for `this.store` for ALL modules, or perhaps use the global `this.$store` everyone else has access to?

Answer (score 0):

Its not ideal but you can just copy the .d.ts into your own shim file and add the store reference to the class. At the root of your project add a file called 'shims-vuex-module-decorator.ts with the below content

```html
import {
  ActionTree,
  GetterTree,
  Module as Mod,
  ModuleTree,
  MutationTree,
  Store,
  ActionContext,
} from 'vuex'
declare module 'vuex-module-decorators' {
  export class VuexModule<S = ThisType<any>, R = any> implements Mod<S, R> {
    static namespaced?: boolean
    static state?: any | (() => any)
    static getters?: GetterTree<any, any>
    static actions?: ActionTree<any, any>
    static mutations?: MutationTree<any>
    static modules?: ModuleTree<any>
    modules?: ModuleTree<any>
    namespaced?: boolean
    getters?: GetterTree<S, R>
    state?: S | (() => S)
    mutations?: MutationTree<S>
    actions?: ActionTree<S, R>
    context: ActionContext<S, R>
    store?: Store<any>
    constructor(module: Mod<S, any>)
  }
  export type ConstructorOf<C> = {
    new (...args: any[]): C
  }

  export function getModule<M extends VuexModule>(
    moduleClass: ConstructorOf<M>,
    store?: Store<any>
  ): M
}
```